# C# console application in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, development

I have created a console application which interacts with Sharepoint Online using Microsoft CSOM and PnP. What I don't understand is how to deploy this code to Sharepoint and run it from Sharepoint. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have included my code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string siteUrl = "";
    string userName = "";
    SecureString password = new SecureString();
    string psd = "";
    foreach (char c in psd)
    {
        password.AppendChar(c);
    }

    AuthenticationManager am = new AuthenticationManager();


    using (var cc = am.GetSharePointOnlineAuthenticatedContextTenant(siteUrl, userName, password))
    {
        // Demo 1: Add empty page
        var page = cc.Web.AddClientSidePage();
        page.RemovePageHeader();
        page.ClearPage();


        var text = new ClientSideText();
        text.Text = "Hello PnP";

        page.AddControl(text, -1);

        page.Save("testpage2.aspx");
        page.DisableComments();
        page.Publish();


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't deploy C# code to SharePoint Online. API you're using is called **Client** Side Object Model. It's meant to be run on SharePoint's client. Now, that doesn't necessarily have to be client computer, it can be another server as well.

Answer (score 0):

**C**lient **S**ide **O**bject **M**odel in SharePoint is meant to be executed on the client machine which can be any system where SharePoint is NOT installed.

Now, if I am not wrong, your CSOM and PnP solution is a console application. Console Applications cannot be deployed. They generate a .exe file which you can run.

If you want to execute CSOM and host it on SharePoint, then you should do it using [SharePoint-Hosted Apps (Add-in)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-started-creating-sharepoint-hosted-sharepoint-add-ins).

Answer (score 0):

Console Application normally runs in a Client computer or a Server.If you want to trigger this application automatically, you can create a Task Scheduler:

[Console Application Using Windows Scheduler](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/manas1/console-application-using-windows-scheduler/)